# Why is my for loop only storing all desired items as one element?

Tags: bash

I am trying to figure out why all items are being stored as one element:

```
        filedates=($dirPath/*.csv)
        filebasenames=()
        filedates2=()
        for file in ${filedates[@]}; do
          filebasenames+="${file##*/} "
        done
        for i in ${filebasenames[@]}; do
                filedates2+="$(echo $i | cut -c6-13) "
        done

        for i in ${filedates2[@]}; do
                echo $i
        done
        echo test here ${filebasenames[0]}
        echo test here ${filebasenames[1]}
```

Im confused because the third for loop prints each element in a new line so I assumed that there is more than one element in the array but when I echo the "test here" line it shows me all the elements in one line indicating that there is only one large string. I verify that with the second echo test here 2 line

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there and fix all bugs: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't appending to the array; you are only appending to the first element of the array. Appending to an array requires parentheses. (Notice, too, that I've dropped the space from the new array element.)

```
        for file in ${filedates[@]}; do
          filebasenames+=("${file##*/}")
        done
```

That said, you don't need a loop at all; you can apply the `##` to all the elements of the array in one operation.

```
filebasenames=("${filedates[@]##*/}")
```

The other array is probably still best populated using a loop.

```
for i in "${filebasenames[@]}"; do
    filedates2+=("$(echo "$i" | cut -c6-13)")
done
```

Comment: @HelloQuantumWorld Also, note the use of double-quotes around all variable and array expansions -- this'll prevent trouble in case of spaces or some other weird characters in filenames.